# AV Foundation, camera capture: conversion between pixel formats or color spaces

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, video-capture

I'm using AV Foundation to capture a video from my webcamera. A webcam can produce video stream only in a limited number of pixel formats, so I want AV Foundation to be able to convert whatever pixel format camera captures in into a desired pixel format, which might not be supported by the camera ( i.e. the AV Foundation framework would need to do the conversion from the pixel format camera can record in into the desired pixel format on its own). I'm looking for YUV to RGB, RGB to YUV, YUv to YUV and RGB to RGB conversions would be fine, similar to what [Color Converter DSP provides in Windows's Media Foundation framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

At first I tried to set the type I want as output in

`-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:@{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(constant)}]`

so that the framework would convert to that type.

I tried using all of the types from [`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/), but got only half of them working and another half erroring with messages in console, which is surprising, since you would imagine that if a pixel format is said to be available -- it would work.

Here are formats from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes` that work for me:

- kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8_yuvs
- kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8
- kCVPixelFormatType_24RGB
- kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB
- kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA

Here are the ones that error:

- kCVPixelFormatType_16LE555
- kCVPixelFormatType_16BE565
- kCVPixelFormatType_16LE565
- kCVPixelFormatType_4444YpCbCrA8
- kCVPixelFormatType_444YpCbCr8
- kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr16
- kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr10
- kCVPixelFormatType_444YpCbCr10

The errors I'm getting are

> "AVCaptureSession warning: Session received the following error while decompressing video: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-6680 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -6680.)". Make sure that the formats of all video outputs are properly configured."

and

> AVCaptureSession warning: Session received the following error while decompressing video: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12905 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12905.)". Make sure that the formats of all video outputs are properly configured."

So I'm a bit clueless here. Is there a way to know which pixel formats would work exactly? It just prints an error to console without actually returning any error values, so it's hard to deduct whether such conversion is possible or not. I'm also not too sure if that's the right way to request AV Media framework to do the pixel format conversion, maybe I should be using only pixel formats supported by the webcam in here and use some other AV Foundation class for pixel format conversion (I found no such class)?